# Installing Android-x86 on a USB (not creating a Live USB)?

Tags: filesystems, partition, virtualbox, virtual-machine, android

I want to carry around an Android OS install on a USB so I can have a Google Authenticator with me everywhere I go since I don't own any mobile devices. The idea being that I can run Android through VirtualBox on the computers I use.

So I first partitioned my 8 GB USB drive using `gparted` into a `fat32` file system for portability.

Then I created a VirtualBox disk associated with the `fat32` partition on the USB drive at `/dev/sdd1`:

```
$ sudo su -
root@ckleinlx:~/.VirtualBox/HardDisks# VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename /root/.VirtualBox/HardDisks/usbdisk.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sdd1
RAW host disk access VMDK file /root/.VirtualBox/HardDisks/usbdisk.vmdk created successfully.
```

Then I downloaded the [android-x86 iso](https://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/list), and attached the iso and newly created `usbdisk.vmdk` as storage on a new VM in VirtualBox.

[image]

Then I boot up the VM and start the installer.

[image]

I formatted the partition again as `fat32` and marked it `Bootable`, then started the install. When asked if I want to install `GRUB` I confirm, installation completes, and I select "Reboot", then shut down the VM.

At this point I remove the Android install disk from the VM, leaving only `usbdisk.vmdk`, which has Android installed on it now. However, when I boot, I just get this:

[image]

Android and grub are both clearly installed on the usb:

```
root@ckleinlx:~/.VirtualBox/HardDisks# mount /dev/sdd1 /media/usb
root@ckleinlx:~/.VirtualBox/HardDisks# ls /media/usb
android-4.3-test  grub
```

And here's what the USB stick looks like in `gparted`

[image]

Why can't Android be booted from this USB? Everything seems to be installed correctly, but virtualbox complains that it can't read the boot medium.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few things that I changed to make it work:

1. Do **not** use the Android installer to format the drive.
2. Create your VirtualBox `vmdk` disk from the device (`/dev/sdd`), **not** the partition (`/dev/sdd1`)
3. Disable the USB devices on the VM: Settings -> USB -> USB Device Filters -> Uncheck all

Answer (score 1):

I install Android to USB with the .iso file and a USB boot maker program (rufus).
There are 2 ways: use 2 USB and use 1 USB only.

- 2 USB: reboot computer > boot with USB > open Install to harddisk > push in the second USB > re detect > ...
- 1 USB: you will need Acronis to split the USB after make a USB boot

  - My USB is 2GB. After make it bootable, I split to 500MB (for the boot data) and 1500MB for install. (After split, you won't see the second drive in explorer and the old driver now is 500MB)  -   -   - MUST be FAT32
  - Reboot > Install to harddisk >... (it will count down) > choose your image size (2047 MB) > reboot > Push out the USB
  - Using Acronis to format the first drive (500MB) > merge second drive to first drive (1500MB to 500MB) (logical now will be primary)
  - OK, reboot your computer and start your android system first time.

I get some problems: some app not work.